# Data structure for an Algebra equation?

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to make an application that is fed in an algebra equation and solves for a given variable of the users choosing.

Pseudocode below

```
enum Variable
    x, pi, y, z; //.. etc

class Value
double constant;
Variable var;

class Term
Value val;              // Might be a variable or a constant
Expression exponent;    // The exponent of this term
boolean sign;           // Negative flag

class Expression
LinkedList<Term>;       // All the terms in this expression
^ This is what I need help on.

Expression exponent;    // The exponent of this term
```

For example the average equation might be:

```
y           =       x        +              (x - 5)^z
^term               ^term    ^ operator     ^ expression^term
```

I need to store this information in some sort of data structure however in order to parse through it. As you see above when I wrote `LinkedList<Term>`, it works but there's no way for me to implement **operators**.

Using the above example, this is how I want my data structure to look like:

```
// Left side of the equals sign
{ NULL <-> y <-> NULL }

// Right side of the equals sign
{ NULL <-> x <-> Operator.ADD <-> Expression: (x - 5) <-> NULL }
```

I can't do this though, because `LinkedList` needs to be of one data type, which needs to be expression.  How should i represent **operators**?

Comment: May I suggest as a subclass of Term ? which, being a relationship, hold necessarily the constraint to have a previous and a next element ?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you mean? Do you mean have my Term class have two fields (right and left) to inform it of what operator is to the left or right of it?

Comment: In your example, Terms are in a linked list. Eventually, elements of a linked list hold themselves references to the previous and next elements of that list. Let say operators are Terms (subclass) with an additional rule : they have literal terms or expression on both side. Now, forget what I said, follow templatetypedef advices and rather use an Abstract Syntax Tree : leaves and nodes naturally carry those properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is significantly easier to work with expressions when you have them represented as abstract syntax trees, tree structures that show the underlying structures of formulas. I would strongly recommend investigating how to use ASTs here; you typically build them with a parsing algorithm (Dijkstra's shunting-yard algorithm might work really well for you based on your setup) and then use either abstract methods or the visitor pattern to traverse the ASTs to perform the computations you need.

ASTs are often represented by having either an interface or an abstract class representing a node in the tree, then having subclasses for each operator you'd encounter (they represent internal nodes) and subclasses for concepts like "number" or "variable" (typically, they're leaves).

If you'd like to get a sense of what this might look like, I implemented a [tool to generate truth tables for propositional logic formulas](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1164/tools/truth-table-tool/) using these techniques. The [JavaScript source](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1164/tools/truth-table-tool/js/) shows off how to use ASTs and the shunting-yard algorithm.

Comment: Hey thanks for such a good response. I'm a third year CS student but I haven't heard of these before. I looked online and could only find that AST's are used to kind of show a problem *before* attempting to make an implementation for it. Is that what you meant? That I need to think more about fully fleshing out this idea? I'm  confused.

Comment: ASTs are definitely used in actual software for solving all sorts of problems (they're used in compilers to represent input programs). I suspect you may need to do a bit more searching.

Comment: Just making sure, ASTs are just like a TreeMap from java but with no provided type,  right? Ex. `TreeMap x = new TreeMap;`

Comment: Oh, that's not the same thing. You're probably thinking ADT (Abstract Data Type), not AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting what you're saying. You mean that I should create either a sublcass or an interface that both `Operators` and `Terms` share, and thus I can now have a Data Structure of my choosing because `Operators` and `Terms` are both of type `MySubclass`. I had thought about this before posting the question but I thought that was considered a really band-aid solution. Unless I am misunderstanding you?